# Term describing a tolerable error in context of software

Tags: programming, software

I am working on some software where the notion of a "less severe" error has now come up as a case to handle, and for logging purposes I want a term to use to represent these. The first to come to mind was "Soft Failure", as I am using "Failure" for the regular more-serious issues. If I do that, though, then it seems like I should rename the original to "Hard Error" by contrast. I'd really rather stick with single-word names, or at least have it be unrelated to the existing Success/Failure dichotomy.

I know this question might be a bit pedantic, but please forgive that as I'm a nut for properly naming things in a concise and descriptive way in my software (which any of you who program know is a good thing for anyone else who works with it).

Currently I'm leaning toward using "Fault", as it almost fits, but a better suggestion would be welcomed.

Edit: Since others seem to have a bit of the wrong idea of what I mean, let me clarify. The term would not be used to refer to a completely unexpected failure - that's what "Failure" is for in the system. This is for expected but rare events that aren't good but aren't a problem in the software. For example, you connect to a database and try to grab a value, but the connection times out due to latency. Another example could be that upon trying to get a value it is missing from the database entirely. Again, this isn't "broken", it's just a missing piece of data, but everything is operating properly. That makes things like "glitch" and "bug" feel ill-suited.

Comment: Then why not use *error* as opposed to *failure*? Error is routinely used to refer to entry (or lack of entry) in sytems, not just computing malfunction.

Comment: Those errors you mention would be errors or exceptions; but recoverable. If you need to differentiate between them - I'd advice an error level or severity level instead of different name. So I'd keep the Error name.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Recoverable is an excellent modifier for this situation! "Recoverable Failure" is pretty clear in describing what I mean. I wish it were shorter or more concise, but barring a better idea I'd pick this as an answer if you post it. The reason for a different name is because these are used on a lookup table for the result of the event, and for filtering purposes I don't want to conflate unexpected failures with minor ones. Perhaps "Unexpected Failure" and "Recoverable Failure" would be a good separation. I suppose I could add a flag that delineates severity or "recoverability"..

Comment: I think you should take your question to a more programming orientated exchange site, because you're moving into a type of design, based on your desire for naming, where it's difficult to advice without going off topic from the English site :)

Comment: True, I had thought of doing that but at first this seemed the more appropriate venue. While the actual solution might involve a difference in design, the word "Recoverable" as suggested by you still wins the day, here, so please do post it as an answer.

Comment: Okay - answer made. (FYI, I would still personally use levels to distinct :) )

Comment: The term "warning" is often used in this sense.

Comment: "occasional anomalies" ?

Comment: This is another case where sticking to a convention is critical--other people seeing the code won't necessarily speak English or get subtle meanings. As suggested elsewhere, this is exactly what "warning" means in this context.

Comment: To take Linux's error-logging as an example, these are the various classes - ranked from most severe to least:  Emergency (system is unusable), Alert (action must be taken immediately), Critical, Error, Warning, Notice (normal but significant), Informational, Debug (reports *everything*, even when all is normal)

Comment: In PHP programming language,  if you choose to display errors you'll get 3 types of errors. 1) errors (fatal or not) 2) warnings and 3) notices. So in your case it's either a warning or a notice.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Most users understand the distinction between **Warning** and **Error**

So, if the issue is fairly mild and recoverable, then you term this as a **Warning** and let the user have some way of rectifying the situation (if applicable).

If the situation isn't rectifiable, then you have at least **warned** the user that something is amiss.

This seems (at least to me) to be understandable and straight-forward (which what we typically want in program messages).

In logging, there's typically three severity levels:
1) *Error* - Something's gone wrong and can't be recovered
2) *Warning* - Something's gone wrong, but it's not too bad
3) *Information* - Nothing's gone wrong, but the event is logged for logging's sake (*x* process has started/finished etc.)

Comment: This is exactly the intention of warning in logging, and is built into any logging system worth the name.

Comment: This is a developer/admin-end part of the system, so the end users *will* see messages in this fashion when things occur. That said, you bring a valid point with sticking to the logging convention that is often used. The rationale behind the usage of Failure/Success is that we're dealing with a data service and so the "request" is failing or succeeding. Perhaps I was trying to shoehorn the notion of severity into the wrong place, though. Since I'm doing work on this part of the system anyway, I will refactor so that it has a separate severity with the standard terminology. Thank you!

Comment: In compilers, *warnings* are also often used to point to patterns that are at risk of introducing unexpected behavior, but which aren't themselves illegal according to the language specification. For example, in C, it is valid to write `if (i = 1) { /* do something */ }` but the *effect* of that is going to be very different from the likely intended `if (i == 1) { /* do something */ }`. For the non-programmers: C, and many languages that derive from C, use `=` for *assignment*  and `==` for *equality comparison*. E.g. Pascal instead use `:=` and `=`, respectively.

Comment: I disagree entirely with your definition of warning. generally, a warning is not used when something is wrong, but when a user has done something typically advised against, either because it is bad practice or could become deprecated in the future.

Comment: @theonlygusti Well, disagree all you want, but that's how the term is used in logging systems.

Comment: There's also **critical**, which indicates that something unexpected and unrecoverable is wrong (e.g., inconsistent/corrupt data).

Comment: Some systems also have a distinction for a critical/fatal error as opposed to just a generic error. It varies but usually a critical error would be unhandleable and represent a fundamental failure, like trying to write to a hard drive that doesn't exist, where a normal error might be recoverable and isn't necessarily fatal (like an IO error on said hard drive).

Comment: @theonlygusti in the context of computing, a "warning" is exactly as described by Pete, and has no implicit relation to a user's action/input. It's certainly possible that a warning is issued because something went wrong (or could go wrong) based on a user's action or input, but can also be an alert to system events.

Comment: @DoktorJ You are wrong, my definition of warning comes from my experience programming and studying computer science; compilers will throw errors, _always errors_, if something goes wrong. If the user (programmer) has instead done something valid, but unexpected or against common convention, a warning may be given.

Comment: For those in this comment section, I think that a very suitable answer to this question would be "warning", it's just that Pete's given definition of warning is completely wrong, in the context of programming and systems development at least.

Answer (score 7):

There's actually a lot of more-or-less standard terminology for this in various bug-tracking systems.

Cosmetic refers to an error that does not affect functionality, but rather is visual only.  Examples include a mis-spelled word, a problem in alignment of two form fields, or inconsistent colors.

Blocking refers to an error that completely prevent some portion of the functionality from working: a form can't be submitted, a report contains no data, etc.

In between those two extremes, you can have intermediate fault levels such as "major" and "minor".

Comment: This isn't a bug tracking system but an audit log for a live system, but the term "Blocking" is useful and I hadn't come across that one - the group I work with generally uses colloquialisms like "showstopper" for things like that. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 7):

**[Recoverable Error](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recoverable-error)** as a distinction from the severe errors / exceptions.

> 1. a program error that can be corrected and does not cause the program to fail or irretrievably lose data.

Comment: Interestingly, this is rather different to how Sun used the term in their high-end file system ZFS. There, a storage device can experience an *unrecoverable error* which is automatically corrected by using available redundant data. In that case, the "unrecoverable" part refers specifically to the physical storage, not the availability of the data as the user is likely primarily interested in. (Of course, if redundant data is not available, then an unrecoverable error *can* indeed result in loss of data.)

Comment: Within the industry - terms and labels are always redefined and used subjectively - because after all - it's language and words and not static definitions.

Answer (score 5):

You want WARNING.  This isn't really an ELL question - in computer land there is a well established hierarchy of errors you are expected to use. For application logging events should generally be categorized into

- FATAL
- ERROR
- WARN
- INFO
- DEBUG
- TRACE

Though in systems land e.g. syslog has [a slightly variant list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level).

Under no circumstances should you be making up your own new names for error or log levels; existing standards for these things ensure understandability by the reader.  Read "[Logging Levels And How To Use Them](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Logging_Levels_and_how_to_use_them.aspx)" for more details.

If you need to name anything else in computer land, please look for existing domain resources and don't just hit the thesaurus.  The next person to look at your code or its output will thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Another example could be that upon trying to get a value it is missing
>   from the database entirely.

In my experience, that would be an *error*. It would have an *error number* and an accompanying *error message*. It might not be a *critical error*, but nevertheless an *error*.

In some systems, there are ***warnings*** in addition to *errors*. For example, the [XSLT 2.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#errors) states:

> When the implementation makes the choice between signaling a dynamic
>   error or recovering, it is not restricted in how it makes the choice;
>   for example, it may provide options that can be set by the user. When
>   an implementation chooses to recover from a dynamic error, it may also
>   take other action, such as logging a warning message.
>
> [Definition: A dynamic error that is not recoverable is referred to as
>   a non-recoverable dynamic error. When a non-recoverable dynamic error
>   occurs, the processor must signal the error, and the transformation
>   fails.]

Comment: For clarity (you're absolutely right in general), the specific situation I was alluding to is default values for fields being pulled from a particular table. It isn't critical that a default value get populated (the user can still select one), but if it's missing then the admin(s) should be able to see so in the log. I probably should have been more specific since a few people were bound to have the experience to know what I was on about.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[glitch](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=glitch)*

> A minor malfunction, mishap, or technical problem; a snag:
>
> *a computer glitch; a navigational glitch; a glitch in the negotiations*

*American Heritage Dictionary*

Comment: This would be better suited to when the event is completely unexpected but minor - I'm talking about things that I expect to happen at some point but rarely, and that aren't good but aren't "broken". Thank you for the input, though.

Answer (score 2):

I like the word *quirk* when you want to convey the notion of something that's a little unexpected but not overtly unwelcome (like an error or a failure).

Definition: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quirk

> Full Definition of quirk
>
> b :  a peculiar trait :  idiosyncrasy
> c :  accident, vagary

Consider also the word *vagary*, listed there as a synonym to quirk.

Comment: Not quite the thing I was looking for, but it would be ever-so-amusing to see "Quirk" alerts in a log. If I end up in a situation where I could make that happen I definitely will, heh. I like the outside-the-box suggestions, which is part of the reason I asked here rather than StackOverflow or etc..

Answer (score 1):

**Hiccup, speedbump, sneeze, deviation, cock-up, bungle, botch, etc. etc...** You could go on all day, and really confuse the daylights out of anybody using your system ("OMG we just had a Mess-Up With Extreme Prejudice!" "No, we're fine, it was just a Pratfall With Light Headwind!") but really, since you're "writing" (you're in this forum, right?) you have to ask yourself one key question: *Who's the audience?*

Since you say it's IT people, they are going to understand the warning/error paradigm -- they'd expect "File transfer succeeded with the following warnings:" or "Transfer failed with the following errors:" but never "Succeeded with errors".  So there you go.  Keep it simple, error vs warning, maybe have "levels" if you have to... don't go too crazy with it.  IMO.